# New Custom Module Page Layout not Showing in CMS Drop Down

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cms, module

I have created a new [custom-module](/questions/tagged/custom-module) for unique page layouts to be used for certain [cms-pages](/questions/tagged/cms-pages) within [magento-1.9.0.1](/questions/tagged/magento-1.9.0.1). The module appears and is enabled in `admin > configuration > advanced menu`.

Despite this, the option for the page layout does not appear in

```
CMS > Pages > Home > Design Tab >Layout drop down menu.
```

I created the following file in: `app > code > local > Custompage > Templates > etc > config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Custompage_Templates>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custompage_Templates>
</modules>
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <one_column_home translate="label">
                <label>1 column home page</label>
                <template>page/1column-home.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>page_one_column_home</layout_handle>
            </one_column_home>
            <!-- add more layouts here -->
        </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
</config>
```

I also have created the following file: `app > etc > modules > Customepage_Templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customepage_Templates>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Customepage_Templates>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Finally I have created a copy of `1column.phtml` in: `app > design > frontend > mypackage > mytheme > template > page > 1column-home.phtml`

A fresh pair of eyes and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few minutes away from the screen, I noticed what I had done wrong.

In the file: app > etc > modules > Customepage_Templates.xml I had the module name incorrect, there was a rogue 'e' in the name 'Custom**e**page_Templates'

I adjusted it to the correct name specified: 'Custompage_Templates'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custompage_Templates>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Custompage_Templates>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you may be missing helper class of your module. Create a helper class of your module by adding this code snippet inside `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <custompage_templates>
            <class>Custompage_Template_Helper</class>
        </custompage_templates>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Now change you custom layout open tag like this

```
 <one_column_home module="custompage_templates" translate="label">
```

Only one step remain. Define helper class inside your module.

File : `app > code > local > Custompage > Templates > Helper > Data.php`

```
<?php
Custompage_Templates_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```